# Excel VBA Userform ListBox Visible=True does not cancel out Visible=False Office 365

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I am facing an issue that I cannot figure out why my ListBox will not show up in the final userform. This is a new issue when I upgraded to Excel Office 365.

Basically I have a with block which contains a whole bunch of additem, sort, etc. which looks like this;

```
 With GUI_Form.ListBox1
     .Visible = False
     'More Code .addItem, Sort, etc. All work fine
     .Visible = True
 End With
 GUI_Form.Show
```

When it shows, everything works well except the ListBox is not visible. Has anyone seen this? As I said, it just started happening with Office 365, worked for all releases before now.

Comment: My with block is specifically for the ListBox object inside the userform. I don't think that has the `.Show` property. As well, I am trying to show the entire `GUI_Form`, which includes the ListBox. I don't think putting it in the with would help, do you?

Comment: Just out of curiosity though, why are you setting the visibility to `False` before the form is even shown?

Comment: To be honest, this is a code that got passed down from who-knows-when and it has just worked since my team has had it..... I'm relatively OK with taking these `.Visible` lines out, but maybe there is a reason they are there. I'm more curious why it has worked for probably 2 decades of VBA and now Excel doesn't like it for some reason.

Comment: any `on error resume next ` somewhere in the code?